# handle null values in a datetime column with DefaultView.RowFilter in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, null, rowfilter

Reading the contents from an xml to a datatable  which is having a date column, and then filtering the datatable with `DefaultView.RowFilter` with certain conditions. It works perfectly with conditions except the ones with date having null values in the column 
Eg.

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter =" StartOn  <=#" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtpToStart.Text) + "#"
```

`if StartOn (date field)` contains any null value it shows following error message

> Cannot perform `'>='`operation on `System.String` and
>   `System.DateTime`.

I tried using  `"isnull(StartOn ,'11/11/2012')<=#"+ Convert.ToDateTime(dtpToStart.Text) +"#"`
but it didn't work.

Comment: You will get many more helpful answers to this question if you include the language you're programming in as a tag. (ETA: Yes, just like that.)

Comment: probably you'll have to do a check on the dtpToStart.Text. Such as `String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtpToStart.Text)` for example. But the few amount of context makes it difficult to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

Check for NULL before the range comparison.

For example:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter ="StartOn IS NOT NULL AND StartOn <=#" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtpToStart.Text) + "#"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did the same but still having issue when StartOn is NULL in DataTable.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error "Cannot perform '>='operation on System.String and System.DateTime."?

Comment: yup..i am getting the same error after adding StartOn IS NOT NULL AND StartOn <= in my rowfilter query.